# Backbone.Marionette: Defer view close until beforeClose animation is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to set animations on rendering and closing an ItemView with Backbone.Marionette. For rendering a view, this is fairly simple:

```
MyItemView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
   ...
   onRender: function() {
     this.$el.hide().fadeIn();
   }
   ...
});
```

This will have my view fade in when I render it. But let's say I want to fade out my view upon close.

```
beforeClose: function() {
   this.$el.fadeOut();       // doesn't do anything....
}
```

This won't work, because the item closes immediately after calling `this.beforeClose()`, so the animation doesn't have time to complete.

**Is there any way, using Marionette as it stands, to accomplish a closing animation?**

---

Alternatively, this is the workaround I've been using:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype, {
    close: function(callback) {

        if (this.beforeClose) {

            // if beforeClose returns false, wait for beforeClose to resolve before closing
            // Before close calls `run` parameter to continue with closing element
            var dfd = $.Deferred(), run = dfd.resolve, self = this;
            if(this.beforeClose(run) === false) {
                dfd.done(function() {
                    self._closeView();              // call _closeView, making sure our context is still `this`
                });
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Run close immediately if beforeClose does not return false
        this._closeView();
    },

// The standard ItemView.close method.
    _closeView: function() {
        this.remove();

        if (this.onClose) { this.onClose(); }
        this.trigger('close');
        this.unbindAll();
        this.unbind();      
    }
});
```

Now I can do this:

```
beforeClose: function(run) {
    this.$el.fadeOut(run);      // continue closing view after fadeOut is complete
    return false;
},
```

I'm new to using Marionette, so I'm not sure if this is the best solution. If this is the best way, I'll submit a pull request, though I'll want to put a bit more thought into how this could work with other types of views.

This could potentially be used for other purposes, such as asking for confirmation on close (see this [issue](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/186)), or running any kind of asynchronous request.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Overriding the `close` method is the one way to do this, but you can write it bit shorter, as you can call the Marionettes `close` method instead of duplicating it:

```
_.extend(Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype, {
    close: function(callback) {
        var close = Backbone.Marionette.Region.prototype.close;
        if (this.beforeClose) {

            // if beforeClose returns false, wait for beforeClose to resolve before closing
            // Before close calls `run` parameter to continue with closing element
            var dfd = $.Deferred(), run = dfd.resolve, self = this;
            if(this.beforeClose(run) === false) {
                dfd.done(function() {
                    close.call(self);
                });
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Run close immediately if beforeClose does not return false
        close.call(this);
    },


});
```

Another idea is to overide the `remove` method of your view. So you fade out the element of the view and then remove it from the DOM

```
remove: function(){
  this.$el.fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).remove();
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Ah... thanks! I knew there must be a simpler way, and overwriting View.remove seems simpler to me. BTW, in the fadeOut callback, you'll need to call either `$(this).remove()`, or `Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.call(self)`

Comment: Overriding the remove function is a better solution than overriding the close method.  That worked great for me.  Thanks.